# Oracle 12c with R2DBC really slow

Tags: oracle, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I'm creating API with Spring WebFlux. My database is Oracle 12c. When I query database by R2DBC then it takes time about 300-1200ms per query even if there is only 1 record in table.

What I'm wrong. Why the query take so long time ?

[My tracking image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ViZl.png)

*1.Repository*

Use coroutines reactive waits the result.

```
@Repository
class ClientRepository(
    private val r2dbcEntityTemplate: R2dbcEntityTemplate
) : BaseRepository<ClientEntity>(r2dbcEntityTemplate) {

    suspend fun getSEQ() = getSEQ("CLIENT_SEQ")

    suspend fun findByClientId(
        clientId: String
    ) = run {
        logger.debug("+findByClientId : {}", clientId)
        val now = LocalDate.now()
        var aa = r2dbcEntityTemplate.select(
            Query.query(
                Criteria.where(ClientEntity::clientId.name).`is`(clientId)
                    .and(Criteria.where(ClientEntity::isDeleted.name).`is`(Flag.N))
                    .and(Criteria.where(ClientEntity::startDate.name).lessThanOrEquals(now))
                    .and(
                        Criteria.where(ClientEntity::endDate.name).isNull
                            .or(ClientEntity::endDate.name).greaterThanOrEquals(now)
                    )
            ),
            ClientEntity::class.java
        )
        logger.debug("done query")
        var bb = aa.awaitFirstOrNull()
        logger.debug("done awaitFirstOrNull")
        logger.debug("-findByClientId : {}", clientId)
        bb
    }
}
```

*2.R2DBC configuration*

use `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:0.9.2.RELEASE` for connection pool.

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
class R2DBCConfig(
    val myConfigProperty: MyConfigProperty
) : AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {

    @Bean
    override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        val descriptor = "(DESCRIPTION =\n" +
                "    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ${myConfigProperty.database.host})(PORT = ${myConfigProperty.database.port}))\n" +
                "    (CONNECT_DATA =\n" +
                "      (SERVER = DEDICATED)\n" +
                "      (SERVICE_NAME = ${myConfigProperty.database.serviceName})\n" +
                "    )\n" +
                "  )"

        val connectionOption = ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.DRIVER, "oracle")
            .option(OracleR2dbcOptions.DESCRIPTOR, descriptor)
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, myConfigProperty.database.username)
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, myConfigProperty.database.password)
            .build()

        val connectionPoolConfig = ConnectionPoolConfiguration
            .builder(ConnectionFactories.get(connectionOption))
            .initialSize(myConfigProperty.database.poolInitialSize)
            .maxSize(myConfigProperty.database.pooMaxSize)
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .validationQuery(myConfigProperty.database.validationQuery)
            .build()

        return ConnectionPool(connectionPoolConfig)
    }

    @Bean
    fun r2dbcEntityTemplate(
        connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory
    ) = R2dbcEntityTemplate(connectionFactory)

    @Bean
    fun transactionManager(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): TransactionalOperator {
        return TransactionalOperator.create(R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory))
    }

}
```

*3.build.gradle.kts*

all dependency which I use in my project.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    application
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.13.RELEASE"
    id("nebula.release") version "16.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Duser.timezone=UTC+7", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")
}


group = "com.demo"
//version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    maven(
        uri("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")
    )
    maven(
        uri("https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/")
    )
    maven(
        uri("https://artifactory.wetransform.to/artifactory/libs-release/")
    )
    maven(
        uri("https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone"),
    )
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.7.3")
//    implementation("com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.7.0.0")
    implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:0.9.2.RELEASE")
    implementation("com.oracle.database.r2dbc:oracle-r2dbc:0.4.0")

    implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.70")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5")


    implementation("org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.1")

    implementation("javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:1.1")
    implementation("javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0")
    implementation("org.apache.axis:axis:1.4")
    implementation("commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.5")
    implementation("javax.wsdl:com.springsource.javax.wsdl:1.6.1")
    implementation(files("libs/webseal.client-1.0.jar"))

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")

    implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0")
    implementation("org.json:json:20220320")
    implementation("joda-time:joda-time:2.11.1")

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-bom:Borca-SR2")
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.4")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

*4.application.yaml*

database configuration

```
spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: /my-context

server:
  port: 8080

my-config:
  api-profile : DEMO
  database:
    host: 192.168.46.131
    port: 1751
    username: usr_sit
    password: Qwertysd
    service-name: DCNET1DB
    pool-initial-size: 10
    poo-max-size: 20
    pool-max-idle-time: 1m
    validation-query: "SELECT 1 from dual"
```

Comment: There are a *lot* of possible reasons for the "slow" response time - app configuration, networking issues, db configuration, db schema architecture, query execution plan, competing workload or resource availability on your app or db servers, just to name a few - that are impossible to diagnose from what you've provided. My suspicion, which I can't prove from what you've provided, is that your connection pool may not have any available threads and that you're having to reauthenticate to the database with every query. That's expensive and takes time. Also `poo-max-size: 20` is probably a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. You can try setting `maxLifeTime = -1` and you will get better response times.

Reference: https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool